# how to combine drawRect: and ImageCache to speed up table view scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to implement my custom `drawRect:` method in my custom table cell in order to speed up tableview scrolling, however, there's an image the app should download from web, so I want to add image cache to my app. The origin implementation of my app is using SDWebImage library, which implement an imageView which offer download image method. If I want to add image in `drawRect:`, how to implement downloading image from web and cache them?

Comment: are you using custom UIView in TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method?

Comment: `SDWebImage` is employing both `NSCache` cache as well as persistent storage cache, so it would take a lot of work to rewrite this yourself. Why don't you continue to use `SDWebImage`? If you don't want to use their `UIImageView` category, then perhaps you will create your own `SDWebImageOperation` operations. Look at their `UIImageView` category source, and you'll see it's quite simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SDWebImage to download and cache the image. Then in delegate/completion block of that download operation, you need to assign the image to your a property and call setNeedsDisplay. setNeedsDisplay will cause your view to be redrawn. This should be called on mainQueue.

```
 [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theArticle.imageURL] options:SDWebImageLowPriority progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {
       dispatch_async(bakground_queue, ^{
       //Here you probably want to dispatch_async to a background queue to do all the image resizing first before drawing on main queue

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               weakSelf.thumbnailImage = image;
               [weakSelf setNeedsDisplay];
           });
       });
   }];
```

In your drawRect, you need to draw from that property. For e.g

```
[self.image drawInRect:rect]
```

This is just basic principle of how this can be achieved. Probably needs more work to really optimize it (e.g cancel the downloading operation when not needed)

Edited:
SDWebImageManager has a delegate method to resize/transform image before storing it to disk cache. You might want to use that method instead of dispatch_async to background queue like above.